# Android how to know when database has finished creating in MVVM

Tags: android, json, mvvm, android-room

I have some json data saved in the assets folder. I use this code to read and process it into data classes I have created:

```
fun getJsonDataFromAssets(context: Context, fileName: String): String =
    context.assets.open(fileName).bufferedReader().use { it.readText() }

inline fun <reified T> extractJsonData(context: Context, jsonName: String): List<T> {
    val jsonList = JSONArray(getJsonDataFromAssets(context, jsonName))
    val gson = Gson()
    val extractedList = mutableListOf<T>()
    for (i in 0 until jsonList.length()) {
        val jsonObject = jsonList.getJSONObject(i).toString()
        val elementOfT = gson.fromJson(jsonObject, T::class.java)
        extractedList.add(elementOfT)
    }
    return extractedList
}
```

Then I add those data classes to my room db callback with this code:

```
private class DatabaseCallback(
        private val context: Context,
        private val scope: CoroutineScope
    ) :
        RoomDatabase.Callback() {
        override fun onCreate(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
            super.onCreate(db)
            instance?.let { database ->
                scope.launch {
                    val ownerDao = database.ownerDao()
                    val dogDao = database.dogDao()
                    val catDao = database.catDao()
                    initializeList("owner.json", ownerDao)
                    initializeList("dog.json", dogDao)
                    initializeList("cat.json", catDao)
                }
            }
        }

        suspend inline fun <reified T> initializeList(jsonName:String, dao: IDao<T>) {
            val jsonList = extractJsonData<T>(context, jsonName)
            dao.addAllT(jsonList)
        }
    }
```

In my main activity I observe Livedata and use it to populate a recyclerview as soon as the app launches. However this make the recyclerview blank for some time.

**How can I add a progress bar or whatever else until the database has been created?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, I would handle this by using Room's support for populating your database from an asset. That's a relatively recent addition to the Room API, and it should be faster than what you have.

Ignoring that, you would need to pass something into your `DatabaseCallback` constructor (e.g., a function type) that could be called from your `onCreate()` function when your work is completed. Whatever is creating your database (e.g., a repository) would provide that `DatabaseCallback` constructor parameter and deal with the result.

So, for example, your constructor could be:

```
private class DatabaseCallback(
    private val context: Context,
    private val scope: CoroutineScope,
    private val onDone: () -> Unit
)
```

...and `onCreate()` could call `onDone()` after inserting all the entries. Or, `onDone` could be a `Channel` on which you `offer()` the result. Whoever is creating the `DatabaseCallback` would supply the lambda expression or `Channel` or whatever, then use that to find out when the work completed.